# How to design API for reports

Tags: api, .net-core, design-patterns

Hi and thanks in advance for ideas.

I have an api endpoint to design which is a report of tickets.
The report itself needs to accept up to 8-10 parameters like start / end date
or start / end product group.
The report then is fairly simple ( Van number, product, quantity ) group by van & product
The API endpoint should represent a resource ( so it would be tickets ) however that would force the API consumer ( a webpage in this scenario ) to calculate the total quantity on frontend.

So I wonder what is the correct pattern here?
Is creating an endpoint for such report wrong way of doing it?
Should I create /tickets/vanloading?startDate=2021-06-28&endDate=.........

What is general approach for different kind of reports when implementing API when there is plenty of data to aggregate ?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean `calculate the total quantity`? Quantity of what?

Comment: @Peppermintology well, the report more or less will be like the below SQL query that should explain it all: SELECT product, sum(quantity), van FROM tickets WHERE startDate = '2021-06-21' GROUP BY product, van; ( more complicated than this , but close enough ). In other words how many of each product I need to put on each Van.

Comment: As you're `sum`-ing the total of each `product` required, before sending the response could you not just `sum` those totals and send that value through at the root level of your response as an overall total?

Comment: @Peppermintology Well, my question is what are the good practices ? Should I : 1. send all tickets so that consumer sum the data they want it or 2. Should I prepare the data for the consumer for viewing without any logic required

Comment: Prepare the data and send it back to the consumer with everything it requires.